# Hiberate Date mapping to MariaDB always returning null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

In my `@Entity` class called `PlayerPoints` I have a `java.sql.Date` field mapped to a *MariaDB* database field with a column with type date. When I query the database with a `JpaRepository` using a query method it always returns `null`.

This is what I have tried so far:

Calling the database with:

```java
PlayerPoints playerPointsFound = playerPointsRepository.findByDatePlayed(matchDay.getDate())
```

```java
Optional<PlayerPoints> findByDatePlayed(Date matchDay); // Does not work

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM player_points pp WHERE pp.date_played = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<PlayerPoints> myOwnFindByDatePlayed(Date matchDay); // Does not work

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM player_points pp WHERE pp.date_played = '2020-06-12'", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<PlayerPoints> myOwnFindByFixedDatePlayed(); //WORKS!
```

In the entity class I have tried adding`@Type(type="date")` but it didn't change anything. I see it bound as a `Date` even without `@Type` annotation, which seems to be correct:

```
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2020-06-12]
```

My database is filled:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                     id: 165
            date_played: 2020-06-12
          player_points: 100
```

Also, I have checked the column types:

```
+-----------+
| DATA_TYPE |
+-----------+
| int       |
| date      |
| int       |
+-----------+
```

My table has been created by using the command:

```
CREATE TABLE player_points (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    date_played DATE NOT NULL,
    player_points INT NOT NULL,
);
```

Anyone any idea why this query always returns `null`?

**UPDATE!**

I have looked into the log files of my mariadb and see that when hard coding the date in the query it results in:

```
SELECT * FROM player_points pp WHERE pp.date_played = '2020-06-12'
```

However, using hibernate's mapping I get the following query (not the date):

```
select playerpoin0_.id as id1_1_, playerpoin0_.date_played as date_pla2_1_, playerpoin0_.player_points as player_poi_pl3_1_, from player_points playerpoin0_ where playerpoin0_.date_played='2020-06-11'
```

So it has something to do with timezones of the application and the mariadb server. I haven't been able to solve that problem, but it is one step closer to the solution.

Regards,

Bart

Comment: The trailing `1` could be a problem in `"SELECT * FROM player_points pp WHERE pp.date_played = ?1"`... That would explain the result of `myOwnFindByDatePlayed(Date matchDay)`.

Comment: Tried without the trailing `1` without success.

Comment: @deHaar that trailing 1 is required by Spring data, i.e. `?1` denotes the first positional parameter. It's more likely that the problem is one of timezones, especially since a day would probably be represented with time 00:00:00,000 so any timezone difference might easily cause a difference by 1 day.

Comment: @Thomas OK, thanks... didn't know that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So like @Thomas suggested, it had to do with timezones.

The mariaDB run on a docker container and followed its `@SYSTEM` timezone -> meaning the timezone of the docker container. This was set to UTC, but my local machine runs in timezone ETC.

Thus, I added `-e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam` to my `docker run` command setting the timezone of my docker container to ETC. Now I see the proper date being logged into the general log of my mariaDB.

Thanks all!